# Writing Cypress Tasks in Typescript

Tags: typescript, cypress

Is there a method that works with the Cypress Typescript `preprocessor pattern for writing tasks in Typescript?

The example here uses a `JavaScript` plugin file:

https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/tree/master/examples/preprocessors__typescript-webpack

**Specifically**

https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/blob/master/examples/preprocessors__typescript-webpack/cypress/plugins/index.js

This does seem to be a bit of a chicken and egg problem though.

After much testing I can't find a way to write and include a Typescript plugin into the JavaScript plugin file. Without compiling the file first via `tsc` then opening cypress.

Mentioned in `Gitte`r is using `ts-node/register` to do it but I can't figure it out.

https://gitter.im/cypress-io/cypress/archives/2019/04/08

Comment: I cannot find any way neither :( did you had any luck or workaround? the more that i've been able to achieve is treat the plugins/index.js file like ts with `//@ts-check` and JSDoc

Answer (score 2):

You should start by installing the Node type definitions:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/node
```

From there, you can continue by replacing all `require` statements with imports, all `export.module` with typescript exports, etc. Since this is all Node, you should be able to migrate your Cypress task files like you would any plain NodeJS file.

The best way to go is just starting with some directory and working your way up from there, fixing build errors as you go along.